# Could what happened to Yeti Airlines Flight 691 happen on an Airbus or Boeing?

Tags: commercial-aviation, boeing-737, airbus-a320, accident-investigation

The Yeti Airlines crash involved an ATR 72 and was likely due to pilot error - a stall resulting in an incipient spin.

Would this accident be more avoidable on say a Boeing 737 or an Airbus A320?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeti_Airlines_Flight_691

Answer (score 4):

The crash of Yeti Airlines Flight 691 on 15 January 2023 was caused by the PM inadvertently moving the propeller condition controls to the feathered position while attempting to set the flaps lever to 30 degrees. Although the PM noticed within half a minute that he had not moved the flaps lever, and corrected this error, he did not notice that he had moved the propeller condition controls instead, and left that part of his error uncorrected.

As the flight crew attempted to continue the landing with no power available, the aircraft stalled while in a left turn at approx. 700 feet altitude.

Attempting to duplicate this crash scenario with a  Boeing 737 or an Airbus A320 would be impossible as these aircraft types are not fitted with a propeller condition control. Because they are not fitted with propellers. They are jets.

Comment: I suppose a follow-up question would be "What would happen if a pilot inadvertently set power to idle while while on approach in a 737 or an A320?" I imagine the answer is "The plane would yell at you until you fixed it."

Comment: Thanks. Are these aircraft even able to stall and descend into an incipient spin? Or are there stabilizing systems in place?

Comment: @Chris Well also just that moving the throttles forward will fix that problem. Part of the issue here is that advancing the throttle doesn't help when the propeller is feathered.

Comment: @Sam Yes, it is possible. There is envelope protection that helps avoid a stall, but it is disabled under certain circumstances or can be disabled by the pilots. This would be a good question to ask on its own if you want a detailed answer (though I would search for duplicates first).

Comment: @Chris if you pull the thrust levers to flight idle on a B737 you would not hear a warning or similar. This happens all of the time during normal descents.  This excludes at low altitudes when the aircraft is not configured properly (e.g. gear/flaps) and thrust is reduced (the aircraft thinks it's landing because of the reduced thrust close to the ground and the gear and/or flaps aren't configured properly).

Comment: @Chris https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_Airlines_Flight_1951